# file is encrypted or is not a database in SQlite Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, encryption

i have been create Database using SQlite Manager (Mozila adds-on), then import some data from csv file then i export the database.

When i import the database into android emulator, database imported successfully. But, when i run some query, then error has appeared **file is encrypted or is not a database**
this my code:

```
public Cursor getTestData()
{
    try
    {
        String sql ="SELECT * FROM `mlokasi` WHERE _id = 1";

         Cursor mCur = myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (mCur!=null)
        {
           mCur.moveToNext();
        }
        return mCur;
    }
    catch (SQLException mSQLException)
    {
        Log.e("Exception", "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
        throw mSQLException;
    }
}
```

Then called the method, something like this:

```
Cursor testdata = myDbHelper.getTestData();

        if (testdata.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Log.d("kab", testdata.getString(0));
            } while (testdata.moveToNext());
        }
```

What's wrong? Please help, thanks

Comment: First of all, your query is wrong. `mlokasi` goes **without** the string delimiters.

Comment: i remove the string delimiters, but has no effect.

Comment: Then you either saved the database with encryption or you aren't passing the proper file to the database engine.

Comment: I just saved the database with 'UTF-8'. Then what should i do?

Comment: Which format? CSV? XLS? XML?, ...?

Comment: I import the database data using CSV. Then, i export the database with .SQL format. I also trying to export with the default format .db, but same result.

Comment: There's your fail: `SQL` is the typical extension for Data Definition Language (CREATE TABLE,... INSERT INTO, ...) files. It's  a plain text file (it's kind of a backup). Not a db file. The database file has typically a `.sqlite` extension.

Comment: Yeah. Greate answer. Thanks @Bob Malooga. I have been trying .sqlite database. Then, work perfectly. My mistake is exporting database while the database has been saved with .sqlite extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake is wrong database format (not plain text). I have changed the database to .sqlite extension, then work fine.